# UIView in UITableView is changing frame automatically

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview, cgrect

I have this `UIView` added to my `UITableView`:

```
self.tableView.addSubview(viewInfoPlus)
self.viewInfoPlus.frame = CGRect.init(x: kWidth - 193 - 32, y: 751, width: 193, height: 103)
```

The one signaled with the red arrow.

[image]

The UIView in the screenshot have the right frame but when I try to reload the UITableView or just some cell/cells using:

```
let indexPath = IndexPath.init(row: 0, section: TableSection.plus.rawValue)            
UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
self.tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
self.tableView.endUpdates()
UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
```

The `UIView` automatically change the frame to the wrong one as you can see in this screenshot.
But when the user scroll to the top of `UITableVIew` the `UIView` automatically change again their frame to the right one.
Obviously I never changed the frame in the code.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood completely the problem.. but I guess you want the popup view to follow the 0€ as shown in first screenshot?

If that's the case, then I think you should addSubview(viewInfoPlus) not to the tableview but to the viewcell instead. But more information on how the viewcontroller is scructured would help ( like if those cards are cells themselves )

Comment: Yes, it is correct. If I add the view to the viewcell It can be showed entirely... it gonna be cropped

Comment: did you try to set the cell clipToBounds to false?

Answer (score 0):

**Use Constraints instead of frame**.

Setting Frames there is no guarantee when resize.  Autolayout allows view that dynamically adjust to different size classes and positions. Check following example

**Example:**

```
viewInfoPlus.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
viewInfoPlus.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
viewInfoPlus.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
viewInfoPlus.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
viewInfoPlus.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 103).isActive = true
```